# How to check on Ubuntu 17.10 the percent power from a bluetooth device at command line?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, bluetooth

Would like to know how to check the charge from a device connected on laptop with Ubuntu 17.10. Tried with bt-device without success (bluez packages):

```
root@ubuntubox:/home/marlon# bt-device -l
Added devices:
Philips SHB3060 (00:11:67:23:D6:31)
```